# java.io.IOException trying to load Java KeyStore

Tags: java, security, keystore

I've started getting a serious problem by the beggining of this week when our customer got new Smartcards version to use on one of our products, during the keyStore loading it throws an exception like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Login failure: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -95)
    at certificate.helper.HelperClass.validateCard(HelperClass.java:194)
    at certificate.helper.HelperClass.retrieveToken(HelperClass.java:107)
    at certificate.view.LoginDialog.validate(LoginDialog.java:144)
    at certificate.view.LoginDialog$1.actionPerformed(LoginDialog.java:84)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

To get things worse, I just can't simulate it on development env!

I started thinking it is something related to user's environment, here our team use Windows 10 x64 + JDK 1.8_x 64, we can simulate this same error in some statios with Windows 7 x64 + JRE 1.8_x x86, our customer got also Linux in some station and they said it works fine.

I tried to change keyStore model and the way it is loaded but it seems nothing solves the problem! Here is how things were done:

```
    public TokenVO retrieveToken(String pin) throws Exception {
    Provider pkcs11Provider = new SunPKCS11(leitorGemPC_Windows())
    Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyStore smartCardKeyStore = createKeyStore("PKCS11");

    validateCard(pin, smartCardKeyStore);
    Enumeration aliasesEnum = smartCardKeyStore.aliases();
   while (aliasesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
  .... things don't even get this far
}

    public void validateCard(String pin, KeyStore smartCardKeyStore) throws Exception {
    try {
        smartCardKeyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    }


public KeyStore createKeyStore(String keyStoreName) throws KeyStoreException {
if (keyStoreName== null || keyStoreName.isEmpty()) {
    keyStoreName= DEFAULT_KEYSTORE;
}
KeyStore smartCardKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreName);
return smartCardKeyStore;

}
```

The only keyStore that really works is the PKCS11, every other I tried don't validate user's Smartcard PIN/Password allowing to use anything even a blank password and return an empty aliasesEnum so that data cannot be retrived from the card.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: what do you expect to happen when your execute: `smartCardKeyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());` and what the method: `createKeyStore()`, does ?

Comment: It is supposed to validate user password and load the keyStore, if the password is wrong it throws some SecurityException. This is how it works using the older Smartcards. I forgot the method you said, sorry. I will edit the original post.

Comment: Basically the method return a PKCS11 keyStore instance. When I tried other kinds of keyStore the method didn't validate the password accepting anything, and returned no aliases.

Comment: Watch out for the method `leitorGemPC_Windows()` ... according to the documentation of [SunPKCS11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) it should return a path to a configuration file, which is platform dependent... and for what I see, the file declares native libraries ...

Comment: You should include name and version of the Smartcard PKCS#11 library you use. Have you tried to use the Smartcard PKCS#11 library in a different product (e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird)? May be the library is defect/incompatible with the card?

Comment: Actually, the card Password is read from a Swing dialog, I am sure it is not the problem as I made it write the password size in the log file just to check if it was missing. The method **leitorGemPC_Windows()** check if the OS is Windows or Linux and return a file path, in Windows case the dll file in the following path c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll

Comment: @Robert the Smartcard we are using is a Gemalto model, I believe the IDBridge CT30 in the link below. We just intalled the driver and use native Java Library, the only external thing that comes to my mind is the dll file I mentioned above [link]http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=pc_usb_tr_and_pc_twin#.V5XnYbgrKUk